# ngTagInput is giving a javascript console error when calling through a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive, ng-tags-input

I'm trying to implement `[ngTagsInput][1]` in my `angularjs` project. Following is my setup:

```
#js file
$scope.loadTags = function(query) {
        $scope.tags = [
            { text: 'just' },
            { text: 'some' },
            { text: 'cool' },
            { text: 'tags' }
          ]
        //return $http.get('/tags?query=' + query);
 }
```

and in my view (myview.html.haml)

```
  %tags-input{"ng-model" => "tags"}
    %auto-complete{:source => "loadTags($query)"}
```

which is same as:

```
   <tags-input ng-model="tags">
        <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
      </tags-input>
```

The above code I copied from the [ngTagInput](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput) plugin website itself. and I'm using CDN to load the same versions as in the plugin website. But when I type tags I'm getting the following error in my JavaScript console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-tags-input/2.0.1/ng-tags-input.min.js:1:5150
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.js:13777:28
    at completeOutstandingRequest (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.js:4236:10)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.js:4537:7
```

It looks like something to do with promises. (I'm pretty new to Angular.js and I'm just guessing), but I wonder how it works in the example given in the [website](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos).

But if I load the tags with the page load, it works fine. What could be going wrong here?

## Edit

After @Pierre comments, my new code looks like this

I probably have forgot the most important part, I'm calling this tags autocomplete method (`in controller`) from a `directive`.

`recipeform.tags` is my model

```
#haml form
 %tags-input{"ng-model" => "recipeform.tags"}
    %auto-complete{:source => "loadTags($query)"}

#js
$scope.loadTags = function(query) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        defer.resolve([
            { text: 'just' },
            { text: 'some' },
            { text: 'cool' },
            { text: 'tags' }
            ]);
        return defer.promise;
        /*return [*/
            //{ text: 'just' },
            //{ text: 'some' },
            //{ text: 'cool' },
            //{ text: 'tags' }
        /*]*/
      }
```

Both the js codes give the same error as previous.

Comment: The fact that your ng-model use the same property than the one you use in the loadTags method ($scope.tags) make me thing you didnt read the directive usage correctly.

Answer (score 3):

```
 <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
```

The "source" is a method supposed to return a promise, which will be used to return the tags. Not to inject them into your model...

```
$scope.loadTags = function(query) {
       return[
            { text: 'just' },
            { text: 'some' },
            { text: 'cool' },
            { text: 'tags' }
          ]
 }
```

should work. If not, it means the directive need a REAL promise, then you will need to do (but I dont think you will need to go this far) :

```
$scope.loadTags = function(query) {
     var defer = $q.defer();
     defer.resolve([
            { text: 'just' },
            { text: 'some' },
            { text: 'cool' },
            { text: 'tags' }
          ]);
     return defer.promise;
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I tried your both the methods and still the same error. I updated my question with the new code. thanks again :)

Comment: I probably have forgot the most important part, I'm calling this tags autocomplete method (`in controller`) from a `directive`. (sorry about that... :()

Comment: I'm not sure to completely understand what you mean by that. You just saying the 'loadTags' method you define in your controller is used/evaluated in the <tags-input> directive, or does it means something else ?

Comment: thanks and yes it is . So I guess I need to find a way to access a the variables in an angular controller, Im calling my directive as `%recipe-form{'recipeForm' => 'recipeFormData'}`, `recipeFormData` is a scope variable from the controller. If u need more data happy to give..

Comment: Currently you'll need to return a real promise for the `autocomplete` directive to work. That'll [be addressed](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput/issues/237) in the next version and a regular array will be accepted (and internally converted into a promise).